# Jupyter Notebook: Typing characters `.0' causes cell to freeze

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

I am using Julia in a Jupyter notebook in a Chrome browser on Windows 10. Whenever I type a dot followed by the number 0, my cell freezes. So for example I try to give a parameter

x ~ Bernoulli(.01)

Everything is fine till I get to Bernoulli(.

But as soon as I type the 0 character, the cell freezes and starts acting weird. I can't add any more input to that cell. I can't select anything. I can't delete anything. Sometimes the same line number starts to display multiple times, without incrementing the line number.

This is happening reproducibly, I checked with the Julia/ Turing community, and they don't think it is from their end. I'm hoping it's either a known issue with Jupyter notebook, or maybe something with IJulia?

Update: This is not happening when I run Python in the notebook. So seems to be somehow IJulia or Julia-related.

Update 2: If I type a 0 following a 0 or following a dot, without any preceding characters, this is triggered. If I type 2.0000 or 200000000 and so on, there is no problem.

Comment: indeed this seems to be a bug as writing `(.0` freezes output in the cell (although it is still accepted and when you run the cell you get a correct result). Can you report this in IJulia.jl issue?

Comment: Added https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/924